# NullReferenceException on an object not null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, nullreferenceexception

I'm passing an object to a view and am getting a null reference exception, but the object is not null.

[image]

In the Action I have this simple code:

```
return View(db.Users.First());
```

View code:

```
    @model User
    @using DG.WEB.Models

    @{
        ViewBag.SecondTitle = "Ver";
        ViewBag.MostraEditarTab = "false";
        ViewBag.MostraApagarTab = "false";
        ViewBag.Tab = "tab2";
        Layout = "~/Views/Conds/_Layout.cshtml";
    }


    <div class="container">
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            <h5>@Model.Nome</h5>

            <div id="container_atalhos">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-th-large"></i>&nbsp;Nova frac</a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-fire"></i>&nbsp;Nova Ocorrência</a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;Novo Fornecedor</a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-file"></i>&nbsp;Novo documento</a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>&nbsp;Editar</a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-mini"><i class="icon-remove-circle icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Apagar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        }else{
           @:Not found
        }
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
I just test a small code that prints the name of the first user in the view.
And it happens to me the same error!
The try / catch apparently works badly ... I do not understand.

Look at the picture
[image]

**EDIT2:**
I found the error. In the layout page there was an error and for some reason visual studio didnt detect it.

Thanks to all.

Comment: can you paste your remaining part of view please ?

Comment: I added the code of view

Comment: In your ALL your images it says "Nome" not "Name" (second letter is 'o' not 'a') ¿Is that correct?

Comment: yes, the property is in Portuguese

Comment: 'FirstOrDefault()' returns null if the result of the query is an empty collection and you just do `.Nome` on it. This is a potential source of the exception. So if you have no data you are basically doing null.Nome which throws the NRE.

Answer (score -1):

Usually such error are not directly related to the place where they blow up, but a consequence of IoC / Dependency Injection.

What basically happens is that in the background, the dependency injection is able to provide various objects as needed, but does this is a *lazy* fashion. So if something - like your layout page - isn't needed yet, it won't be created yet.

So then when you access something like your model, which can have internal requirements needing something like your layout, then the dependency injection kicks in, throwing an error at your model, even though the error is not model-related at all.

This is one of the really difficult aspects of dependency injection and will probably plague you again in the future :(.

There is also no best-practice I know of to avoid this. Your approach to gradually cornering the issue is the best way to go ahead AFAIK.